# Security error when create new role with field_security

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic, you can create roles. For the same index, I would like to create a role to display some fields and for another role hidden some fields.

For that, I found that in the doc 'field_security'.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-overview/7.3/field-level-security.html

Currently I use an Elastic + Kibana version 7.3.1 in a Docker container

My request for create role is :

```
POST /_security/role/myNewRole
{
  "cluster": ["all"],
  "indices": [
    {
      "names": [ "twitter" ],
      "privileges": ["all"],
      "field_security" : {
        "grant" : [ "user", "password" ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And response is :

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "current license is non-compliant for [field and document     level security]",
        "license.expired.feature": "field and document level security"
      }
    ],
    "type": "security_exception",
    "reason": "current license is non-compliant for [field and document level security]",
    "license.expired.feature": "field and document level security"
  },
  "status": 403
}
```

I checked the license with request :

```
{
  "license" : {
    "status" : "active",
    "uid" : "864f625a-fc7a-41de-91f3-c4a64e045a55",
    "type" : "basic",
    "issue_date" : "2019-09-10T10:04:38.150Z",
    "issue_date_in_millis" : 1568109878150,
    "max_nodes" : 1000,
    "issued_to" : "docker-cluster",
    "issuer" : "elasticsearch",
    "start_date_in_millis" : -1
  }
}
```

My docker-file

```
version: '3'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.3.1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=toto
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
      - "xpack.security.enabled=true"
      - "xpack.security.dls_fls.enabled=true"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    networks:
     - net
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.3.1
    environment:
        - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=elastic
        - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=toto
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
     - net  
volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local

networks:
   net:
```

How to fix this licensing problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Even though basic security features are [free with a BASIC license](https://www.elastic.co/blog/security-for-elasticsearch-is-now-free), "field and document level security" are only available to [Platinum-level users](https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions)... and to Elastic Cloud users.

So the most simple and not too costly way of getting this feature is to [subscribe to Elastic Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/pricing).

Comment: Is there an resource that marks the API endpoints, or parts of the argument objects that are illegal at each License level? For example field_security and "query" appear to be disallowed in the roles call at Basic license level.

Comment: @Jontia yes here: https://www.elastic.co/subscriptions#elastic-stack-security

Comment: That link was already in your answer, and its obviously quite high level. I was thinking more of something explicitly low level. Like [this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-api-put-role.html), but with a notes next to the request body items specifying the license level.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not explicitly listed anywhere